# Linq Expression to String

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

Here's a simple method in MVC that converts into html tag.

```
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.myName);
```

This is converted into the below html.

```
<input type="hidden" name="myName" value="ABC..." />
```

How this expression is converted into the string. Let's suppose If I want to write this kind of method, how can I know the property name and its value. Suppose from the HiddenFor argument, how myName & myName value will be extracted.
This is not specific to MVC but related to LINQ expression.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: This is a very broad topic, way too broad to explain over the course of a single SO answer.  You can look up the documentation for `Expression` to see what information it exposes, and you can find lots of information on how an expression can be parsed on SO and elsewhere.

Comment: You may look at the source code of mvc  (and input extensions) here : http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/System.Web.Mvc/Html/InputExtensions.cs

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This has nothing to do with LINQ (except that LINQ makes heavy use of those "expression trees").

`model => model.MyProperty` is a lambda expression which can be *parsed* when treated as an `Expression<Func<Model, T>>` instead of just a `Func<Model, T>`.

Let me answer your question by a (mostly self-explanatory) example:

```
public static string GetPropertyName<T>(Expression<Func<Model, T>> expr)
{
    var member = (MemberExpression)expr.Body;
    var property = (PropertyInfo)member.Member;
    return property.Name;
}
```

which can be used as follows:

```
public class Model
{
    public int MyProperty { get; set; }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    // Prints "MyProperty"
    Console.WriteLine(GetPropertyName(model => model.MyProperty));
}
```

Comment: Where did you define the Model & T types for GetPropertyName function and how Html.HiddenFor works without defining the TModel & TProperty?

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the ExpressionHelper class in the Mvc source

https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/9c545aa343ccb1bf413888573c398fe56017d9ee/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Core/Rendering/Expressions/ExpressionHelper.cs

The method GetExpressionText converts the lambda expression in question

Comment: Can you please tell me where the template types are defined for @Html.HiddenFor in MVC architecture. Template types that are referred as TModel & TProperty.

Comment: The generic type arguments are inferred by the compiler. It is not required to specify them explicitly.

Comment: Thanks Jonas, sorry for late respond, but what I searched so far is generic types can't be inferred automatically, so is it specific to MVC? Am still confused how the generic types are inferred in mvc and why not in any simple console app?

Comment: This is applicable for C# in general. The code example in Heinzi's answer will work in any project type.

Comment: This is what I am getting when trying to run the Heinzi's sample code.The type arguments for method 'LinqPractice.Program.GetPropertyName<T,Model>(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<System.Func<Model,T>>)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

Parsing expressions is hard. I had the same issue and there is a much simpler solution.

Although it is not as elegant, it is quick, easy, short and **it handles subclasses**.

`Expression.Body.ToString()` actually works and returns the whole expression as a string. The hardest work is to process the string afterward:

```
class Program
{
    public class Car
    {
        public int Id;
        public CarModel Model;
        public string Owner ;
    }
    public class CarModel
    {
        public string Name;
        public string Brand;
    }

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ExpToString(x => x.Id));
        Console.WriteLine(ExpToString(x => x.Owner));
        Console.WriteLine(ExpToString(x => x.Model));
        Console.WriteLine(ExpToString(x => x.Model.Name));
        Console.WriteLine(ExpToString(x => x.Model.Brand));
    }

    // The inelegant solution that works
    public static string ExpToString<T>(Expression<Func<Car, T>> exp)
    {
        var s = exp.Body.ToString();
        return s.Remove(0, s.IndexOf('.') + 1);
    }
}
```

The output:

```
Id
Owner
Model
Model.Name
Model.Brand
```

I am actually using this in WinForms for data binding initializations and I am pretty satisfied with it.